# Get Time Zone Information in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way that Outlook Macro can detect the time zone to which the computer's time is configured to?

I would like to use this in querying for mails in a time range

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.Timezones.CurrentTimezone`.

Comment: Even better! Nice one.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Can you give an example of usage? like initializing a Dim and printing it in a msgbox

Comment: What kind of example? Msgbox Application.Timezones.CurrentTimezone.Name